# Proving that if $A\times (B \cup C)=A\times (B \cap C)$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that if $A\times (B \cup C)=A\times (B \cap C)$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=C$.

Proof by contradiction:

Givens: $A\times (B \cup C)=A\times (B \cap C)$, $A\neq\emptyset$, $B\neq C$.

Suppose $x\in A, y \in B$ so $y\not\in C$, then $(x,y)\in A\times (B \cup C)$.

So $(x,y)\in A\times (B \cap C)$ so $y\in B\cap C$ but since $B\neq C$ then $y\in B\cap C=\emptyset$ is a contradiction, thus:

If $A\times (B \cup C)=A\times (B \cap C)$ then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=C$.

Is anything missing?

Comment: "...$y\in B$ so $y\notin C$..." How do you come to this conclusion? And how do you know that some $y\in B$ exists? $B$ could be empty.

Comment: @drhab, I supposed $y\in B$. $y\not\in C$ because $B\neq C$.

Comment: and what if $y\in B\cap C$? Then $y\in B$ **and** $y\in C$. Also if $B\neq C$. You are confusing $B\neq C$ with $B\cap C=\emptyset$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct, but without contradiction it's easier.

Suppose $A\ne\emptyset$ and let $x\in A$. Consider $y\in B$: then $(x,y)\in A\times(B\cup C)$, so $(x,y)\in A\times(B\cap C)$. Therefore $y\in B\cap C$. This means $B\subseteq B\cap C$ and so $B\subseteq C$. By symmetry, $C\subseteq B$.

What's wrong in your argument? If $y\in B$, $y\notin C$ is not certain. However, you *can* take $y\in B\setminus C$ or $y\in C\setminus B$ and such an element certainly exists because $B\ne C$.

Comment: Almost correct? I disagree on that.

Comment: @drhab I explained the error which is in a misunderstanding of what $B\ne C$ means. But it's easily fixable, because the element can indeed be chosen in $B$ but not in $C$ (or conversely). I would have discussed it in this way during an oral examination.

Comment: Easily fixable? I agree on that :).

Comment: @drhab I believe in promoting students' self-esteem: saying them “it's wrong” when the argument is fixable, is bad. But “almost correct” is not “correct”.

Comment: I think that - in spite of my initial disagreement - we are on the same line anyway. Especially when it comes to your attitude towards students.

Comment: @drhab I learned it the hard way. A kid that had been my student as a high school freshman and started with his mouth closed and wandering eyes when I asked him something and ended the year with “passed”, in his sophomore year (with another teacher) came to me telling how he had done an exercise. It was correct, albeit not along the straightest path. The teacher said to him: “Wrong”. He didn't study much, to be honest, but he had had a spark! Of course he came to think that math is impossible and closed the door to it. :(

Comment: That is indeed a very sad story. With a very valuable lesson in it for you (and indirectly for the ones you share it with, like me). However, the pain of the closed door still remains. I weep with those who weep now :(.

Answer (score 2):

This looks mostly right, but you have to be a bit more careful. If you assume $B \neq C$, then you don't necessarily know $B\cap C = \emptyset$. Further, you don't know that there is necessarily $y \in B$ such that $y \not\in C$ (it could be the case that $B \subsetneq C$). It is true that either

- $\exists y \in B$ such that $y \not\in C$

**OR**

- $\exists y \in C$ such that $y \not\in B$

which is enough to make your proof work.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is wrong. It is not true that $B \cap C = \emptyset$.

$B \neq C$ is equivalent on saying that $( B \setminus C \neq \emptyset$ or $B \setminus C \neq \emptyset)$.

In the first case you can pick $y \in B$ and $y \notin C$, and use your argument.

In the second case you can use the same argument exchanging the roles of $B,C$.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed is $A\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq C$.

The first assumption guarantees the existence of some $x\in A$.

The second guarantees the existence of some $y$ that belongs to $B\cup C$
and does not belong to $B\cap C$ (there is an element in $B$ that is not in $C$ or there is an element in $C$ that is not in $B$).

Then $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times\left(B\cup C\right)$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A\times\left(B\cap C\right)$
so $A\times (B\cup C) \neq A\times\left(B\cap C\right)$

Answer (score 1):

This is not feedback on your proof, but this is just to show an alternative style of proof: expand the definitions, and then use the laws of logic to simplify the result, and see where that leads you.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$We calculate as follows:

$$\calc
\tag{*} A \times (B \cup C) = A \times (B \cap C)
\calcop={set extensionality; definitions of $\;\times\;$, twice, and of $\;\cup\;$ and $\;\cap\;$}
\langle \forall x,y :: x \in A \land (y \in B \lor y \in C) \;\equiv\; x \in A \land (y \in B \land y \in C) \rangle
\calcop={logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \in A\;$ from both sides of $\;\equiv\;$}
\langle \forall x,y :: x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; (y \in B \lor y \in C \;\equiv\; y \in B \land y \in C) \rangle
\calcop={logic: write $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$; split into independent quantifications}
\langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \rangle \;\lor\; \langle \forall y :: y \in B \lor y \in C \;\equiv\; y \in B \land y \in C \rangle
\calcop={logic: apply the 'golden rule' $\;P \lor Q \;\equiv\; P \land Q \;\equiv\; P \;\equiv\; Q\;$}
\langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \rangle \;\lor\; \langle \forall y :: y \in B \;\equiv\; y \in C \rangle
\calcop={definition of $\;\emptyset\;$; set extensionality}
\tag{**} A = \emptyset \;\lor\; B = C
\endcalc$$

Therefore we've not only proven that $\ref{*}$ implies $\ref{**}$, but we've proven them equivalent.

Yes, it's more symbols than the other answers-- but the good news is that all steps are of the type "there's really only one thing you can do", so if you know the laws of logic, it is almost trivial to write down.

Comment: Very nice, is 'golden rule' really its name?

Comment: Also, in the second to third lines, why did $x\in A\wedge (...)\equiv x\in A \Rightarrow (...)$?